# Swift default implementation of a superclass method

Tags: ios, swift

Consider a base class `A` which defines a function `f()` which should be overridden in subclasses to customize behavior:

```
class A {
    func f() -> String {
        return "A"
    }
}

class AA: A {}
class AAA: AA {}
class AAAA: A {}
```

Now I want to add some subclasses to the hierarchy tree where A is the root, and all of those subclasses return the same thing from `f()`:

```
class B: AA {
    override func f() -> String {
        return "X"
    }
}

class C: AAA {
    override func f() -> String {
        return "X"
    }
}
```

Since I hate copy-pasting every time the same implementation of `f()` I would like to move it to a common place. Since base classes are different and out of my control, I thought maybe protocol extensions can help. I wanted to do something like this:

```
protocol P {
    func f() -> String
}

extension P {
    func f() -> String {
        return "X"
    }
}
```

and then just conform my classes to protocol `P`, hoping that I will get the default implementation in every class:

```
class B: AA, P {}
class C: AAA, P {}
```

However, this is not working:

```
let x: A = C() // the same with just "let x = C()"
print("result: \(x.f())") // prints "result: A"
```

Not sure why, maybe because of static dispatch of protocol extensions, or because the protocol brings the same function name as base class and the latter "wins", have no idea. Is there a way to achieve something similar to this in Swift?

**Rationale:** I am tired of copying the same code of making a controller portrait-only into each of them that is designed to have such a limitation:

```
override var shouldAutorotate: Bool { return false }

override var supportedInterfaceOrientations: UIInterfaceOrientationMask { return .portrait }

override var preferredInterfaceOrientationForPresentation: UIInterfaceOrientation { return .portrait }
```

Comment: The answer to the first 85% of your question is different from the solution you should use for the last 15% under your "Rationale" section. For the view controller part, simply create a `UIViewController` subclass and then have all of your app's view controller subclass that. Then all of your app's view controllers will be portrait only without replicating any code.

Comment: What about having portrait-only tab controllers, navigation controllers, etc? I have different controllers and I cannot stick my PortraitOnlyController between them and their base class UIViewController. That's why I mentioned that I have no control over the class hierarchy and that there are bunch of classes there, like AA, AAA, etc

Comment: You don't need to worry about tab controllers and nav controllers. They determine what orientations they support based on the view controllers they contain.

Comment: Do you suggest to have only plain UIViewControllers in my code, never inherit UINavigationController, for example?